# why doesn't the favicon file show in the address bar of google chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, favicon, address-bar

I have put favicon.ico file in the root directory.The favicon file is shown in the address bar and title bar of firefox and IE but is shown only in the title bar of google chrome. Why is that ?

Comment: Are you really just asking why chrome chooses not to show them to the left of your current address even though you see it in the tab bar?

Comment: @ xaxxon why are you surprised ?

Comment: I just figured you would have pulled up every other site on the internet and seen the same behavior and realized there was no difference.

Comment: @ xaxxon Yeah ! i checked many.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The globe icon in Chrome's address bar refers to whether or not the current site uses HTTPS, a common web security protocol. Since Chrome doesn't display favicons in this region, your site is working properly.

No SSL:
[image: No SSL]

SSL :
[image: SSL]

Mixed SSL/No SSL:
[image: Mixed]

Comment: Kind of defeats the purpose of the generally accepted favicon. Why not display a protocol icon and a favicon? I always wonder at Google's way of thinking.

Comment: @LordofScripts: It's not just Chrome, Firefox also show a padlock and not the favicon.  See http://www.wired.co.uk/news/archive/2012-04/25/firefox-fires-favicon

Comment: The reason is pretty simple, a malicious site could use a lock as favicon and trick users into believing that the connection is encrypted.

Comment: You can have both. Google has amazing designers on staff. "Hey design team, we need a way to show the favicon on the address bar without interfering with clearly indicating that a site is secure or not."