# favicon.ico with CherryPy 3.2.2

Tags: cherrypy, favicon

I am running CherryPy 3.2.2 under Python 3.2.2 (coincidence!).  I include in my server configuration the element:

```
        "/favicon.ico":
                        {
                          "tools.staticfile.on": True,
                          "tools.staticfile.filename": 
                                 "/myhome/myserver/favicon.ico"
                        },
```

However the server does not show my icon in my browser's address bar.  Any hints?

To be more precise, in Chrome and in Firefox, the icon does show up in the tab label but not in the address bar; in Seamonkey it does appear in both -- that's what I would like it to do under any browser.  Maybe it is not a CherryPy problem?

-- tsf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be working correctly.  There is no way to get favicon to be in the url bar for certain browsers...

[why doesn't the favicon file show in the address bar of google chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864813/why-doesnt-the-favicon-file-show-in-the-address-bar-of-google-chrome)