# How to display the logo on the address bar?

Tags: html, favicon

I want to show logo on the address bar. But it is visible only on tab next to title.

```
<link rel="icon" href="http://www.mydomain.info/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />      
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.mydomain.info/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Comment: What browser? Chrome does not show the favicon in the addressbar. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864813/why-doesnt-the-favicon-file-show-in-the-address-bar-of-google-chrome

Comment: Your format seems to be correct already

Comment: I think the same thing is true for Firefox.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37073/what-is-currently-the-best-way-to-get-a-favicon-to-display-in-all-browsers-that

Comment: Neither does Mozilla, earlier they used to. Now it is being used to show that lock symbol for security and trustworthiness.

Comment: HTML Or CSS cannot do anything here, it's the browser built in that way..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: yes. That's how many browsers work.

Firefox: http://msujaws.wordpress.com/2012/04/23/an-update-to-site-identity-in-desktop-firefox/

Chrome: [why doesn't the favicon file show in the address bar of google chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864813/why-doesnt-the-favicon-file-show-in-the-address-bar-of-google-chrome) and http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/kUQOKVUwUmw

In the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon), you can find some more about browser support. In short, Firefox and Chrome don't do it, Explorer, Safari and Opera do.

Answer (score 5):

It is up to the browser to decide where/whether to display a favicon.

Chrome reserved the addressbar for the address and an indication of the protocol.

There is not much you can do about it.