# Fav icon not showing in address bar

Tags: html, favicon

My fav icon in address bar does not showing in Chrome and Firefox. But it shows in Internet Explorer. It is showing in title bar, but not in address bar. I want to make it visible in address bar also for all major browsers.

Comment: can you please mention the format that you linked the favicon in html page?

Comment: can you post your code used for favicon or provide the url of your site?

Comment: Check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18458697/how-to-display-the-logo-on-the-address-bar) for FF and Chrome in address bar

Comment: below is my code<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

Comment: Thank you for helping me...I got the solution...Chrome and Firefox recently removed the favicon property from their address bar.for more security they added a default Padlock instead.

Comment: You don't need that code. Instead just upload your (favicon.ico) to your root directory and it will display on all pages in sub directories and in all browsers :)

Answer (score 2):

Visit http:// url-to-your-site.com/favicon.ico

You should now see your favicon now both in the address bar and on the screen, if you get a 404 then you've uploaded it to the wrong location.

Chrome and Firefox cashe favicons, and for some reson shift+f5 doesn't seem to work. You'll see your favicon if you visit your site in an incognito window too (Ctrl+shift+n) in Chrome